# Creating a running aggregate of users to date in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have table that has users with unique IDs and a date field for when the account was created. I am able to generate a query that can tell me how many people signed-up within a particular week of the year. However, what I am interested in is the number of users that signed up historically + that week. Does anyone have any ideas?

Constraint, I have read only access to the database and can not write new tables and columns.

I've successfully gotten the counts broken up by week, but I can't not figure out how the table can refer to itself to get a running total.

Comment: you can add your code

Comment: Does a query `select count(*) from table_name;` give you what you want to know? If not please give the table definition and sample data and required output.

Comment: *number of users that signed up historically + that week.* This is "before the end of this week". Trivial task when you do not look on the solution for previous task and solve this task from the same beginning.